# Unknown letter preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

Just quick question, I'm using preg_match to get a information from the URL, but I found a problem.

The letters "avadasa" are always different, how I can tell the script that this is not important. I want my script to skip it and leave just "Name-Of-Article"

http://example.com/**avadasa**/Name-Of-Article

Thanks for help

Comment: edit your question to include code of what you a currently trying, an example of what is incorrect, and an example of what is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "http://example.com/avadasa/Name-Of-Article";
preg_match('#^http://(?:www\.)?example\.com/[^/]+/([\w-]+)$#', $url, $match);
$name_of_article = $match[1];
echo $name_of_article;
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/lpewtU)

Comment: Doesn't work like this. Before I had like this "preg_match('/^http\:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/avadasa\/([\w\-]+)$/is', $url, $match);" what I have to do to replace avadasa ? I try to put there [^/]+ but it doesn't work.